# Problema al instalar plugin "Llamada telefónica" en Ionic 3

Tags: ionic

es mi primera vez instalando un plugin en ionic, por lo que lo he instalado siguiente las instrucciones de la web oficial, los siguientes pasos:

```
1) $ ionic cordova plugin add call-number
2) $ npm install --save @ionic-native/call-number
```

La primera linea muestra un mensaje de instalación ok, pero la segunda aparece el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi pregunta es si ese mensaje es peligroso para cuando genere el .apk? debo cambiar algo? o no me preocupo y funcionará de igual manera?**

*Mi ionic info:*

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0
global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.1
System:
    Node : v6.11.3
    npm  : 3.10.10
    OS   : Windows 10
Environment Variables:
    ANDROID_HOME : not set
Misc:
    backend : legacy
```

*y mi package.json:*

```
{
    "name": "crist",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
        "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "angular-linky": "^1.2.2",
        "angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
        "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
        "ionic-angular": "3.6.1",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "rxjs": "5.4.0",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.4",
        "typescript": "2.3.4"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Es solo una advertencia de npm... comprueba que tu programa funcione en tus dispositivos localmente y si todo va bien no te tendrías que preocuparte

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias, pensé que podría traer algún tipo de problema ,saludos

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer necesitas actualizar tus paquetes de **Ionic**.

Instala la nueva versión de Ionic de manera global y local:

```
npm install -g ionic@latest
```

Actualiza la carpeta de **node_modules** de tu proyecto:

```
nom install
```

Vuelve a instalar el plugin